# PropertyModel cannot work with Kotlin's private field with get()

Tags: kotlin, wicket

If a kotlin's model has a field :

```
class MyModel {
  private val theValue: Double
    get()  { return 1.0 }
}
```

and in the wicket page :

```
new PropertyModel(model , "theValue")
```

It will fail :

```
WicketRuntimeException: Property could not be resolved for class: class MyModel expression: theValue
```

The solution : remove the private modifier :

```
class MyModel {
  val theValue: Double
    get()  { return 1.0 }
}
```

Is there any way to get around this (keep the private modifier) ?

(wicket 7.9.0 , Kotlin 1.2)

Comment: why should it be private if its necessary to access it from outside the class?

Comment: Thanks. I took it as java's private field with public getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the model needs to be read and written, it is necessary for your model to have a property with backing field.

```
class MyModel {
  private val theValue: Double
    get()  { return 1.0 }
}
```

Does not have a backing field, even if you remove the `private` modifier.

Try it like this:

```
class MyModel {
  var theValue = 1.0
}
```

or if you need `equals()`, `hashCode()` etc. out of the box:

```
data class MyModel(var theValue: Double = 1.0)
```

Note: Wicket is a Java framework. In it's [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/model/PropertyModel.html) it is explicitely stated, that you need a Java bean as model, which it is in the second code snippet.